Why is VSCode reverting my simple-import-sort sorting of imports in this particular file?
I asked Run autofix to sort these imports! on eslint simple-import-sort/imports plugin in TypeScript a while back, but now I got everything working pretty much. If I run eslint --ext .tsx,.ts . --fix it fixes the files, but when I manually save this particular file, it reverts back, then shows errors. (Notice how in the image it is flickering when I press CMD+S).


I am on the latest VSCode as of today Sept 5, 2024 (just installed the VSCode update)
I restarted VSCode several times.

The error it shows is:

Run autofix to sort these imports!eslintsimple-import-sort/imports.


Why is this happening?
And how do you fix this issue?

I am not that great with ESLint yet, but here is my .eslintrc.json:
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.yaml", "*.yml"],
      "parser": "yaml-eslint-parser"
    }
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "sort-exports",
    "typescript-sort-keys",
    "sort-keys",
    "prettier",
    "unused-imports"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "prettier",
    "next",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "curly": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/array-type": [
      2,
      {
        "default": "generic"
      }
    ],
    "react/display-name": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/await-thenable": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-exports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/method-signature-style": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-empty-export": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type": "error",
    "no-array-constructor": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor": "error",
    "no-throw-literal": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": "error",
    "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members": "error",
    "object-curly-spacing": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"],
    "padding-line-between-statements": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {
        "blankLine": "always",
        "prev": "*",
        "next": ["type"]
      }
    ],
    "space-before-blocks": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks": ["error", "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": [
      "error",
      { "after": true }
    ],
    "import/no-duplicates": "error",
    "sort-exports/sort-exports": "off",
    "typescript-sort-keys/interface": "off",
    "typescript-sort-keys/string-enum": "off",
    "sort-keys": "off",
    "sort-keys/sort-keys-fix": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "default-case": "off",
    "default-case-last": "off",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
    "simple-import-sort/imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "groups": [
          ["^react$", "^next", "^[a-z]"],
          ["^@"],
          ["^~"],
          ["^\\.\\.(?!/?$)", "^\\.\\./?$"]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

And here is my .vscode/settings.json:
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": "always",
    "source.organizeImports": "always",
    "source.sortMembers": "always"
  },
  "css.lint.unknownAtRules": "ignore",
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "typescript"],
  "eslint.nodePath": "./node_modules/eslint",
  "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never",
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": "on",
    "comments": "off",
    "strings": "on"
  },
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]
}

I must have conflicting rules or something, but I've tried quite a few things (removing this and that eslint rule), but nothing has an effect other than setting the sort import rule to off (which I don't want, I want autofixing imports).

remove source.organizeImports from editor.codeActionsOnSave inside the settings.json.
